# Javascript on .each class getval

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

thanks for looking at this question.

I have a issue as I got few text field

Their id is as followed

Row 1:

```
 height_1,weight_1,cost_1
```

Row 31:

```
   height_31,weight_31,cost_31
```

Row 61:

```
   height_61,weight_61,cost_61
```

Total will have 90 rows.. so the problem in the past is

Its work because I will use the javascript below to calculate the total of this 90 rows.

```
for(i=1;i<=90;i++)
{

$('.height').each(function () {
heightTotal += Number($(this).val());    
})

$("#height_row_A").html(heightTotal);

$('.weight').each(function () {
weightTotal += Number($(this).val());    
})

$("#weight_row_A").html(weightTotal);

//cost is just about the same so I leave it out
}
```

So the problem now is, in the past the 90 rows are calculated together and append to this span id **height_row_total and weight_row_total**

But now I need to calculate row 1 to 30, row 31 to 60 , row 61 to 90

Each have their on row span at the top of their row

which followed like this

Row 1

```
height_row_A,weight_row_A
```

Row 2

```
height_row_B,weight_row_B
```

Row 3

```
height_row_C,weight_row_C
```

How do I change my this

```
$('.height').each(function () {
heightTotal += Number($(this).val());    
})

$('.weight').each(function () {
weightTotal += Number($(this).val());    
})
```

to only get row 1 to 30, instead of every value with the id height
and then to get row 31 to 60 and 61 to 90

My code segment is something like this example of a field. the 1 will change to 2 on the next row, there is total 30 rows x 3 column

```
<tr><td>1</td>

<td><input class="height" type="text" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 13px;" name="height_1" id="height_1" tabindex="1" value=""></td>

<td><input class="weight" type="text" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 13px;" name="weight_1" id="weight_1" tabindex="2" value=""></td>


For Row 2
   <tr><td>2</td>

    <td><input class="height" type="text" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 13px;" name="height_2" id="height_2" tabindex="3" value=""></td>

    <td><input class="weight" type="text" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 13px;" name="weight_2" id="weight_2" tabindex="4" value=""></td>
```

What I wanna to do is fetch the total height for row 1 - 30 , and display in a span id "total_height_for_col_1" and the same for weight

Then row 31-60 will be for col_2 and 61-90 will be for col_3

My [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsddffx1/3/) , for the JsFiddle example, I got 4 boxes.

With the javascript, I wanted to able calculate the total for box 1 and 2, then box 3 and 4.

This example used only 4 boxes, in reality I got 90 boxes, and split by 30 per span id

Comment: Are all rows inside the same tag?

Comment: can you provide an example of DOM lookalike please ?

Comment: @artm and Guilaume , I added my code sample

Comment: I'd seen the sample but it's not clear what the dom looks like, so as Guillaume suggested, add a dom lookalike or a jsfiddle with 5-6 sample rows.

Comment: @artm, i added jsfiddle

Comment: JsFiddle Updated again, to /3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use something more powerful like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs).

This will allow you to easyly manipulate the arrays (remember that `$('xxx')` returns an array).

To get the ranges, use [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

To get the value of each element as number use [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map)

To calculate the sum use [_.reduce](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce)

Something like this:

```
_.reduce( 
     _.map( $('.height').slice(0,30), function(x){ return Number($(x).val());}), 
     function(accumulator, val) { return accumulator + val; })
```

(Obviously you need to slice by 30,60 and 60,90 to get the other results).

Explanation:

- `$('.height')` returns an array of HTML elements
- `_.map` applies the callback function to each element to get its value
- `_.reduce` uses the callback to update the accumulator for each element (As there is no initial value specified for the accumulator, the first value will be use to initialize, and the following values to update it)

If you want to use plain javascript:

```
var ac=0;
var $elements = $('.height');
for(var i=0; i<30; i++) { 
  ac = ac + Number($($elements[i]).val());
};
```

Comment: is javascript able to achieve the same thing

Comment: Of course. lodash itself is written in javascript. If you want to do it with pure javascript, use `for` or `foreach`. Or use jquery + `slice` (which is an standard array function). But why not using a library that simplifies solving a problem?You're using jQuery to make DOM manipulation simpler. Use lodash to manipulate arrays and collections.

Comment: I not very experience with javascript, I am normally a php coder, but as my project require javascript usage. My row will stay fixed and unchanged at 1-30 for first column, 31-60 for second column, 61-90 for third column. and I just need calculate the total height for each column.

Comment: The result of `_.reduce` or the value in `ac` is the value you're looking for. What's the problem? NOTE that the 0,30; 30,60; 60,90 are intentional because the array index is zero-based.

Comment: I tried to run alert(ac) after the last line, it return NaN, but if I run alert within the for loop its work.

Comment: I've tested the code in Chrome console. It works fine. Get sure that your selector `$('.height')` selects the expected elements. You can enter the console pressing F12 (in most browsers) and run the code line by line, and inspect the variable values. (I prefer Chrome's console but you can use Firefox's Firebug, or the IE console)

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/rsddffx1/4/

It should work if your html matches the fiddle, separate tables with multiple rows in them, first row first column being the index. If your html is different it needs to be changed. I made some changes to the html to change span class names and to add class to tables. No need to keep count of < 30 then else between 30 and 60 or else greater than 60 because each table has its own span for the sum.

I do an each on the tables, get the table index, .each row get the index value from the first column, add the matching height and weight, then update the span depending on the table we're checking. It looks something like this:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){

    $(".table").each(function (tableIndex, table){
        var height = 0;
        var weight = 0;

        $(this).find("tr").each (function (rowIndex, row){

            var firstColumnValue = $(row).find("td").first().text();

            height += parseFloat($("#height_" + (firstColumnValue)).val());
            weight += parseFloat($("#weight_" + (firstColumnValue)).val());

        });

       $("#total_" + (tableIndex + 1)).text(height + " " + weight);
    });
});
```

if each table first row first column doesn't have an index in your production html, I can change the function to get the row index from the parent table, instead of reading it.